# android Button is not working correctly according to result value

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I am trying to call intent only when the result field have value "yes", otherwise it should disable the button. Can anyone please help. It works only one time. 
I have dynamic records that have result value set to "no" and only few records have result value set to "yes".
Problem is my code works if i directly check "yes" value result but if I check "no" value result before it doesn't work.

Below is my code-

```
    holder.results.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             /*Intent intent = (new Intent(context, Result.class));
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             intent.putExtra("id", id);
             Log.d("id",holder.did.getText()
                       .toString());
             v.getContext().startActivity(intent);*/
             if (getItem(0).getId().length() > 0) {
                 Log.d("result",holder.result.getText()
                           .toString());
                 /*if(holder.result.equals(holder.did.getText()
                           .toString())){*/
                 if(holder.result.getText()
                           .toString().contains("yes")){
                 Intent intent = (new Intent(context, Result.class));
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 intent.putExtra("id", holder.did.getText()
                   .toString());
                 Log.d("id",holder.did.getText()
                   .toString());
                 v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                 }
                 else if(holder.result.getText()
                           .toString().contains("no")){ 
                     holder.results.setEnabled(false);
                 }
                } else {
                    holder.results.setEnabled(false);
                // C.ToastShort(context, "no data available");
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try making `holder.results.setEnabled(true);` inside `onCreate()`

Comment: what is results? is that a button or a textview?

Comment: @SaeidFarivar result is textView and results is button.

Comment: @Aniruddha I am using Custom Adapter.

Comment: @user3705697 once you get it as "no" then you are not able to do anything, right? Is that the problem you're facing?

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but I think you should work on naming your variables. It's a good practice to give defining names to variables, for example, a TextView that has results, could be called tvResults, a Button that has something to do with results, could be called bResults. Also, why are you creating a copy of newly created Intent?  When you click the button, and it does not contain "yes", it gets disabled and does not react to further clicks, am I right? I think you should put your logic in TextWatcher.

Comment: @Aniruddha no that is one part of solution. One shouldn't be able to do anything if result is "no". here Button should only work when result is "yes".

Comment: @Marius I've worked on naming my variables. This code is in my custom adapter file which is being used only to set values. But with every set of values I have button with them. Yes u r right that if clicked on button and result value is "no" then it should be disabled and intent shouldn't work.

Comment: @user3705697 Once disabled, button can't enable itself - something else has to enable it.

Comment: yes I got your point Marius. Thank you my code is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Marius and others for helping me. I have enabled the button before disabling it i.e. when result have any other value except "yes" and also removed else if part of "no" value. Below is my working solution.

```
  holder.results.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (getItem(0).getId().length() > 0) {
                 Log.d("result",holder.result.getText()
                           .toString());
                 holder.results.setEnabled(true);
                 if(holder.result.getText()
                           .toString().contains("yes")){
                 Intent intent = (new Intent(context, Result.class));
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 intent.putExtra("id", holder.did.getText()
                   .toString());
                 Log.d("id",holder.did.getText()
                   .toString());
                 v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                 }
                } else {
                    holder.results.setEnabled(false);
                // C.ToastShort(context, "no data available");
                }
        }
    });
```